# LaravelCollective DatetTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I am using Laravel5.2 and the LaravelCollective form and html helpers.

I have a field in my database called fixture_date which is of type datetime.

In my view I am using

```
{{ Form::label('fixture_date', 'Date:') }}
{{ Form::date('fixture_date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()) }}
```

This just produces a date selector and when submitted enters
2017-01-12 00:00:00 into the database.

If i change my view to

```
{{ Form::label('fixture_date', 'Date:') }}
{{ Form::time('fixture_date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()) }}
```

I get a time selector but when I submit then I get an error as data is missing ( the date part)

Is there a way of getting a datetime selector in there for that field as I need this for both create and update.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try using the format method available:

`{{ Form::time('fixture_date', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('H:i')) }}` as the time field is expecting this 24 hour time format by default.

Comment: it will only show time i want both date and time like this 2010-05-10 10:30:05 how i can do it

Comment: @Moaiz Change the format from 'H:i' to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' I believe. Check PHP date formats if unsure

Comment: It select the today date not other the day after or the day before

Comment: I want date and time both @jonathan